# Dry & sandy bare spots

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I have very dry sandy soil. Even though I have irrigation, I overseed and aerate each year, some places just will not fill in. Can these places be sodded?

Comment: Lots of mulch might help.

Comment: Do you fertilize? If the grass isn't growing in the sandy soil its because sand doesn't provide nutrients so you are going to need to fertilize regularly sodded or not.

Comment: How often do you run your irrigation system? Daily? Weekly? And how long do you run it each time?

Comment: Paula, check out some of our other question/answers about lawns.  First question is where do you live or rather what type of grass are you growing?  Cool season or Warm season.  Very important.  I'll bet there is something wrong with your maintenance habits; mowing too short, watering too shallow, too often and/or improper fertilization.  Good that you aerate once per year!  You should never have to worry about using sod for patches because that sod will suffer whatever happened to the the grass in those patches.  Waste of money.  Please send pictures and more information.  Thanks!

Comment: It's unlikely to be the same problem a friend had with a "bald patch" on a lawn which didn't respond to any kind of treatment over several years. Eventually, it was found that there was a leak in an underground natural gas pipe. I guess plant roots don't grow well when the soil is full of methane, not air!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP hasn't returned to provide the additional information asked for in comments that might allow respondents to arrive at a solution to the problem.